# uuid.uuid1() returns pretty similar results

Tags: python, python-3.x, uuid

I've generated uuid's by `uuid.uuid1()` in Python and they all look pretty similar. Why is that? How to randomize them?

[image]

Comment: UUIDs are designed to be *unique* and not *as different from each other as possible*.

Comment: @KlausD., similar? why similar? they aren't.

Comment: Please use full sentences! It will help to understand your point.

Comment: @KlausD., are they similar? why are they similar? they aren't similar.

Comment: The "why?" is explained below. The other two parts of your comment are a matter of perspective. For the requirement of uniqueness a one bit difference is enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because the `uuid1` is generated from your machine ID and time stamp and the machine ID in your case remains constant, that's why they look pretty similar at the end. You may use `uuid4()` to get a random unique [uuid](https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html).